# Select subelements with a class from element which is stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

HTML:

```
<div class="view">
    <span class="number">40000</span>
    <br/>
    <span class="number">50000</span>
    <br/>
    <span class="number">240000</span>
    <br/>
</div>
<div class="view">
    <span class="number">60000</span>
    <br/>
    <span class="number">70000</span>
    <br/>
    <span class="number">350000</span>
    <br/>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(".view").each(function(i,foo){
    $($(foo).html()).filter('.number').each(function(index,Element){
    }
```

How to elegantly select only the `.number` elements which are children of a selected `.view` which is in foo variable ?

Comment: what is `foo` in this case? Are we talking about some sort of click event selecting a specific `.number.` span, and grabbing all the spans next to it?

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand what "with an element stored in foo variable" means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.view').find('.number')
```

Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes:) Thank you. $(foo).find('.number') did the job

Comment: You want to hit the up arrow on the Answer, and also Mark it as one if it helped you out!

Answer (score 3):

You can try this

```
$('.view > .number');
```

OR

```
$('.view').find('.number');
```

OR

```
$('.number' , '.view');
```